# Player termination with basketball agent

Tags: basketball

I have a question that is not related to this "player opinion contract". It is about a player who wants to terminate the contract with his agent. I would like to ask after the player has sent the Notice of termination (in the written terms) does he need to receive from the agency a confirmation that the contract is terminated or the player is already no longer represented by that agent?

Answer (score 1):

It depends based upon the wording of the contract. If in the contract it is stated that the player may terminate employment at any time, the agent is not working for the player the moment the formal letter of termination is signed.

Source: Years and years of research about becoming a sports agent